# How to get attributes of a parent class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

How do I get the attributes of Class A, a parent class (super class), to use it in Class C in Java.

For instance:

```java
Class B extends A

Class C extends B
```

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Java using eclipse @TylerH

Comment: IDE is unrelated, by the way

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843021/access-a-private-variable-from-the-superclass-java

Comment: @LynnLee have you solved your problem? If so please mark an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the member protected:

```
public class A
{
    protected int myInt = 5;
}

public class B extends A
{
}

public class C extends B
{
   public int GetInt()
   {
     return myInt;
   }
}
```

private member can be accessed only by the class itself, protected by the class and all the derived classes.

Comment: Don't forget package-private (default) access.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is best to keep attributes private, and access them via accessor (getter) and mutator (setter) methods from any other class, including derived classes. If the variable must or should be accessed directly from subclasses, which occasionally is desirable but not usually, then nearly always declare it protected.